# Errors after upgrading Ubuntu from 19.04 to 19.10

Tags: upgrade, 19.04, bios, software-sources

I was trying to download a package and I couldn't do it because the sources.list contained links that were deprecated.
While upgrading, I saw the following error:

```
 An upgrade from 'disco' to 'focal' is not supported with this tool.
```

So, I searched and came across this link [Cannot upgrade from disco 19.04 to focal 20.04 after end of life using do-release-upgrade method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1260939/cannot-upgrade-from-disco-19-04-to-focal-20-04-after-end-of-life-using-do-releas)
In it's comments, I came across this link https://tips.graphica.com.au/upgrading-from-retired-ubuntu-releases/

Briefly, I did the following steps:

1. Edited /etc/apt/sources.list to point to:
   "deb [http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu"](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu%22) and not any other repository.
2. Ran sudo apt-get update && sudo spt-get upgrade
3. The 19.04 was fully updated and upgraded and I could install softwares from there.
4. I tried to now update to 19.10 and then to 20.04. For it, I ran command: do-release-upgrade
5. It said that disco to focal is not possible.
6. So, I followed the link specified earlier and I modified  ~/.cache/update-manager-core/meta-release
7. I found out that, there disco, eoan, focal were present in which only focal's supported parameter was 1 so I changed the supported parameter of Eoan and disco to 1 too
8. Then I ran the command do-release-command.
   It was running smooth. 2 hours were past. I was left at a purple screen for half an hour. I pressed power off button and restarted the system with Ubuntu. The grub's look was a bit changed which specified that it got installed., but then when I clicked on Ubuntu, following error was present. This is the picture after I clicked on BIOS.

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't use the power button to shutdown the computer (didn't SysRq keys allow you to command the kernel to shutdown?  that's safer!). Given you did, like a power-outage, I'd suggest you boot a *live* media and `fsck` (or check your file-systems) before you attempt to boot your system. A re-install (without format) would have been faster & allowed skipping 19.10 jumping straight to 20.04 (and not touch user files, only system directories are wiped & packages re-installed).

Answer (score -1):

You cannot upgrade from an unsupported release (19.04, and b.t.w., even your target release, 19.10, currently is not anymore supported). You always should remember upgrading while your current release is still supported.

At this stage, a fresh reinstall is your only option to install a newer and supported system.

Comment: A downvote, OK, but that is the answer nevertheless. Like it or not.